# VB.net ComboBox auto drop down on input

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I want to create a ComboBox that automaitcally drops down the words containing the letter based on the input. My dropdownstyle is dropdown so the combobox has an input field.

For example i would input the letter A or a I want the ComboBox to automatically dropdown the words which contains the letter A or a. The contents of the ComboBox are being set by myself manually.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want is filtering for the combo box items

Comment: it think your case it will be better to use `autocomplete` property if `Textbox` instead of `ComboBox`

Comment: i want to see the list of words that contains the letter i have inputted on dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set these

```
AutoCompleteMode: SuggestAppend
AutoCompleteSource: ListItems
DropDownStyle: DropDown
```

Suppose your combo has these items then you have to add them to the autocompletecustomsource also

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add("10")
ComboBox1.Items.Add("92")
ComboBox1.Items.Add("9000")
ComboBox1.Items.Add("9001")

ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("10")
ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("92")
ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("9000")
ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("9001")

ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
```

Comment: I want to make the DropDownStyle into simple but when I click the drop down words it will not fill up the input field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible via the `AutoCompleteMode` and `AutoComplete`, like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
               ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

        'Add some options
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("ABC")
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("BCD")
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("CDE")
    End Sub

    'Add ComboBox1.Text to AutoCompleteCustomSource collection when leaving ComboBox
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
               ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Read [AutoCompleteMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode.aspx) for more information.

Read [AutoCompleteSource Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletesource.aspx) for more information.