# letting user type and add value to an already bound combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have one combobox in my app that gets populated with a dozen or so items from SQL SERVER. I am currently trying to allow user to be able to type in a new value into the combobox and save it to a table in SQL SERVER. I'm looking for something along the lines of a DropDownStyle of DropDown and DropDownList. Basically I'm hoping to let the user type in the combobox, however if the value is not there, i want to be able to give them an option of saving it (probably on lost focus). I'm wondering what would be a good way of doing something like that.

On lost focus should I basically go through each item that is currently in the drop down and check it against the value entered?

EDIT:

```
    Sql="SELECT IDvalue, TextName from TblReference"
    Dim objconn As New SqlConnection
    objconn = New SqlConnection(conn)
    objconn.Open()

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, objconn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da.Fill(ds, "Name")

    If ds.Tables("Name").Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim dr As DataRow = ds.Tables("Name ").NewRow
    ds.Tables("Name").Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0)
    With c
         .DataSource = ds.Tables("Name")
         .ValueMember = " IDvalue "
         .DisplayMember = " TextName "
    End With
    End If
```

Comment: Please show the code that adds the items to your combo. Are you using the DataSource property or are you adding the items one by one with Add?

Comment: @steve - see edit! C- is a comboboxname passed to this function

Comment: Uhm, I think you need something like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845736.aspx but, as far as I know there is no functionality built in for the standard combobox. It seems that the only possible way is to handle the Leave event and check if the ComboBox.Text  is present in the ds.Tables("Names") rows

Comment: The way I have always done that is to add a small edit button.  When they click it, a dialog comes up which will add to the data source if the code approves it.  PS your code is leaking

Comment: @PLUTONIX that's what iw anted to do but gods said no. WHERE?! it seems to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already adding a fake/blank row to a table, you can do the same thing for a new item.

```
' form level datatable var
Private cboeDT As DataTable
```

Initializing:

```
cboeDT = New DataTable

Dim sql = "SELECT Id, Descr FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY Descr"
Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, dbcon)
        dbcon.Open()

        cboeDT.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())

        ' probably always need this even
        ' when there are no table rows (???)
        Dim dr = cboeDT.NewRow
        dr("Id") = -1       ' need a way to identify it
        dr("Descr") = ""
        cboeDT.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0)
    End Using
End Using

cboeDT.DefaultView.Sort = "Descr ASC"

cboE.DataSource = cboeDT
cboE.DisplayMember = "Descr"
cboE.ValueMember = "Id"
```

**Note** Users  tend to have a preference as to the order of these things.  The simple creatures tend to prefer alphabetical over a DB Id they may never see. To accommodate them, the `DefaultView` is sorted so that any new rows added will display in the correct order.

Add new items in the Leave event (much like Steve's):

```
Private Sub cboE_Leave(sender ...
    ' if it is new, there will be no value
    If cboE.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
        ' alternatively, search for the text:
        'Dim item = cboeDT.AsEnumerable().
        '    FirstOrDefault(Function(q) String.Compare(q.Field(Of String)("Descr"),
        '                                                            cboE.Text, True) = 0)
        'If item Is Nothing Then 
        '    ' its new...

        Dim newid = AddNewItem(cboE.Text)

        Dim dr = cboeDT.NewRow
        dr("Id") = newid
        dr("Descr") = cboE.Text
        cboeDT.Rows.Add(dr)

        ' fiddling with the DS looses the selection,
        '    put it back
        cboE.SelectedValue = newid
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to search by text:

```
Dim item = cboeDT.AsEnumerable().
    FirstOrDefault(Function(q) String.Compare(q.Field(Of String)("Descr"),
                                                            cboE.Text, True) = 0)
If item Is Nothing Then
    ' its new...
    ...
```

Inserting will vary a little depending on the actual db.  A key step though is to capture and return the ID of the new item since it is needed for the CBO:

```
Private Function AddNewItem(newItem As String) As Int32

    Dim sql = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (Descr) VALUES (@v); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"
    Dim newId = -1
    Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, dbcon)
            dbcon.Open()

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@v", MySqlDbType.String).Value = newItem

            ' MySql provides it in the command object
            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                newId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.LastInsertedId)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using

    Return newId
End Function
```

As noted `MySql` provides the `LastInsertedID` as a command object property. In SQL SERVER, tack `...";SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"` to the end of your SQL and then:

```
newId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

This is not conceptually very different from Steve's answer, except it uses the `DataTable` you build rather than collections which makes it (very) slightly simpler.

Comment: thank you for this. finally am able to give this a try. I needed to change the DropDownStyle to DropDown so that I could type text and it would not limit it to only the stuff in the combobox. However, if I start typing the name of an item in the drop down - it only appear when i do the Down Arrow Key. Is there a way to automatically open the drop down as if they clicked on it and display all items for the text entered. Or just a different way of automatically finding the item being typed?

Comment: Okay so I was able to find this out with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670245/vb-net-combobox-auto-drop-down-on-input   So this work because it automatically opens the drop down however, another issue. I use a function to adjust the width of the drop down when user clicks on it. In this case the suggestions only are displayed in the same width and the drop down. AHHHH. DropDownwidth  doesn't apply to that

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this, is on window load I perform a new SQL query to get the list of values in the table, and load them into a combobox.

Then once focus is lost, it then checks what's currently typed into the combobox against the current values already loaded. If it doesn't exist, then it's not in SQL. Something like the following...

```
    Dim found As Boolean = False

    For i As Integer = 0 To comboBox.Items.Count - 1
        Dim value As String = comboBox.Items(i).ToString()
        If comboBox.Text = value Then
            found = True
        End If
    Next

    If found = False Then
        'the item doesn't exist.. add it to SQL
    Else
        'the item exists.. no need to touch SQL
    End If
```

Comment: but this will only go through the loop once if it doesn't find it the first time. because if it doesn't meet the first and second conditions, i don't want it to go to the sql until it loops through every single value

Comment: I'm a little confused, It will loop through every value once. If it finds the value, it doesn't try to add it, because it's already there and stops the loop. If it doesn't find the value, after looping through every value, it will add it. There is no reason to continue the loop if it finds the item?

Comment: Edited answer, that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I was like what is he talking about... smacked my head and then realized it lol. Don't forget to mark as answer if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is to build a simple class to hold your values through a List of this class

```
Public Class DataItem
   Public Property IDValue As Integer
   Public Property TextName as String
End Class
```

Now, instead of building an SqlDataAdapter and fill a dataset, work with an SqlDataReader and build a `List(Of DataItem)`

```
' Class global...
Dim allItems = new List(Of DataItem)()

Sql="SELECT IDvalue, TextName from TblReference"

' Using to avoid leaks on disposable objects
Using objconn As New SqlConnection(conn)
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, objconn)
    objconn.Open()
    Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
       While reader.Read()
          Dim item = new DataItem() With { .IDValue = reader.GetInt32(0), .TextName = reader.GetString(1)}
          allItems.Add(item)
       End While
    End Using
    if allItems.Count > 0 Then
       allItems.Insert(0, new DataItem() With {.IDValue = -1, .TextValue = ""}
       Dim bs = new BindingList(Of DataItem)(allItems)
       c.DataSource = bs 
       c.ValueMember = "IDvalue"
       c.DisplayMember = "TextName"
    End If
End Using
End Using
```

Now the code that you want to add to your Leave event for the combobox

```
Sub c_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles c.Leave
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text) Then
        Dim bs = DirectCast(c.DataSource, BindingList(Of DataItem))
        if bs.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.TextName = c.Text) Is Nothing Then
            Dim item = new DataItem() With { .IDValue = -1, .TextName = c.Text}
            bs.Add(item)

            ' here add the code to insert in the database
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```